# Java @Inject not working - method returns null

Tags: java, mockito

Not sure as to why the interface doesn't get injected. The test always returns null. I've got the `beans.xml` as well in `WEB-INF`. Why does it return null?

I've also tried to annotate the service class with `@ApplicationScoped` and a class that produces a new `TImpl`

```
public interface T {
 int test_method(int n );
 public void addToSession(Session session);
} 

@Handler // Qualifier
public TImpl implements T{

 private static Set<Session> sessions = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());
 public TImpl();

 @Override
 int test_method(int n){ return n * 2; }

 @Override
 public void addToSession(Session session){ 
  sessions.add(session);
}
}

public class TService implements Serializable {

 private @Inject @Handler T;

 public TService() {}
 ... 

 int test_method_service(int n) { return T.test_method(n); }
 public void addToSession(Session session) { T.addToSession(session); }

}

public class L extends Endpoint {

 TService service;

 public L(TService s){ this.service = t; }
 public L(){}


 @Override
 public void OnOpen(Session session, ... ) 

 servive.addToSession(session); // null pointer
 ...
}
```

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.vio.sockets.configuration.MessageEndPoint.onOpen(MessageEndPoint.java:40)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.init(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:133)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:914)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: It is injected, but you have mocked it, so the mock is injected.

Comment: Anyone? I still have no clue why it returns null. I'm running TomEE, CDI 1.1.

Comment: @Matsemann - I don't think It's injected, as I don't get null only when I test it.

Comment: do you think you have missed a qualifier on TService?

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare I don't know. Have I?

Comment: yes, probably try adding @Handler on TService too

Comment: I've tried. Same result. I've added the stacktrace as well.

Comment: you have to mock T's behaviour like Mockito.when(T. test_method()).thenReturn()

Comment: If it wasn't injected the code would fail with nullpointerexception, not return 0. You have to tell the mock what to do.

Comment: Your `TService` is not correctly written down here. There’s no variable name for the `T` typed member, and you perform the call on the type `T`, not a variable.

Comment: @Michael Piefel I've used T to shorten the code. I don't want to copy/paste it all

Comment: And it’s still wrong, not short.

So what is the _interface_ that doesn’t get injected? Your stack trace shows thas `service` is `null`, that’s a class. So, the `TService` instance is not injected in `L`.

Answer (score 0):

You say that your test returns `null`, but the stacktrace tells a different story: `expected:<6> but was:<0>` is not a `NullPointerException`, it means that the call to `service.test_method_service(3)` return 0 – that’s zero.

This seems just like the expected behaviour of a Mockito mock: You have a mock for `T` injected into your `service` instance, it calls `test_method()` in the mock for T, and Mockito’s default value for methods returning `int` is 0.

When you want a different behaviour, you have to set the mock’s behaviour:

```
Mockito.when(t.test_method(3)).thenReturn(6);
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it returns 0. I do get a Nullpointer if I use it outside jUnit. I've edited the question.

Comment: Wow, so now you’ve edited the question in a way that turns the whole thing completely around. Your tags are wrong now.